# Horizontal space before block of text

Tags: formatting, margins, indentation, description, text-manipulation

[image: desired text spacing]

Hi, I wanted to create column of text after bolded "Lorem Ipsum 1.", which has no specified linebreaks. This space before text (marked on image with red line and question marks) should have exact width of "Lorem Ipsum 1." How can I do it in LaTeX?

Comment: Do you need page breaking of this block, or will it always appear on a single page?

Comment: Can't guarantee it will always appear on a single page. Page breaking would be welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `enumitem`'s description list:

[image]

### Notes:

- This properly handles the text going across page boundaries.
- If you don't want a blank line between the two, simply add the `nosep` option as in `\begin{description}[leftmargin=!, labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries #1},nosep]`.
- [The `showframe` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe)
  was used just to show the page margins.
  It is not needed in your actual use case.
- [The `lipsum` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was used just to provide dummy text. It is also not needed in your document.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\MyEntry}[2][]{%
    % #1 = label
    % #2 = content
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=!, labelwidth=\widthof{\bfseries #1}]
        \item [#1] #2
    \end{description}
}%


\begin{document}
\MyEntry[Lorem Ipsum1.]{\lipsum[1]}

\MyEntry[Phasellus elementum 2.]{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it be possible not to create newline after description?

Comment: @Mike: Yep, use `nosep` option. Have added a comment in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

A variant, also using the `description environment` and `enumitem`. I define a `sommaire` environment (from the french term that describes that type of typographical composition — I don't know how to translate it in English). This environment takes a mandatory argument, which is the “title”, and an optional argument, which is the value of `\parindent` inside the environment (default is 0em). I don't know how to hand the current font on to the environment, so as to use it for the title font (description defaults to roman boldface), hence I had to code the font family in the environment code.

I give an example with several paragraphs and indentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}

\newenvironment{sommaire}[2][itemindent=1em]{
\newlength\mymarginwd\settowidth{\mymarginwd}{\bfseries#2\enspace} \setlength\listparindent{1em} \begin{description}[style=sameline, labelindent=0pt, #1, leftmargin=\mymarginwd, font = \sffamily]%
\item[#2]\setlength\parindent{\itemindent}
}%
{\end{description}}

\begin{document}

\sffamily
\vspace*{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{sommaire}{Lorem Ipsum 1.}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{sommaire}

\end{document}
```

[image]